# Excel - Format Date Value to Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having dates in my `excel` sheet 2013. I need to convert them to TEXT. So when I go to `Format Cells` & select `TEXT` option, then the value changes to something else.

`For e.g If i have date as 01/01/2016, when i change it to TEXT the value becomes '42370'.`

How to change the format of cell to `TEXT` by retaining the correct value?

I tried doing formula `=TEXT(C6,"dd/mm/yyyy")` but formula has to be written in a different cell. What if i have to change it in the same cell?

Comment: Add an apostrophe before the date:  `'01/05/2016`.  `=ISTEXT(A1)` will return TRUE then, but `A1+1` will still return `02/05/2016`

Comment: I got the solution here :- http://www.excelfunctions.net/convert-date-to-text.html

Comment: By selecting - Data > Text to Columns

Answer (score 0):

You may try following steps:

1. select cells what you want to change.
2. mouse right click > Format Cells
3. Number tag > Custom
4. Write `dd/mm/yyyy` in Type box > OK

---

other method

```
sub DatetoString()
    dim rng as range

    for each rng in range("A1:A10")
        rng.value = format(rng.value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    next rng

end sub
```

Comment: As i did the above, the format of the cell still remains as `Date`

Comment: So you want to change them into string at where they are?